# Definition of MMA

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new to this site, and I have noticed a common abbreviation: MMA. What does the abbreviation MMA stand for? The abbreviation seems to be used frequently among senior members of this website. Searching via Google was not useful because of the more common usage in mixed martial arts.

Comment: sometimes some write `MMA` as short cut for `Mathematica`. Some others use just `M` as short cut. Some write the full name `Mathematica`.

Comment: It probably comes from the fact that `mma` is an official shortname for _Mathematica_. If you type `mma` inside a text cell, it will automatically replace it with _Mathematica_.

Comment: This might be a question more suited for chat, or a comment below a post where this abbreviation was used.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I disagree. It took me some time to figure out what `mma` (and `OP`) stand for as well.

Comment: @Ajasja My comment was not about whether this could be a genuine question (it is) but more what the most appropriate location might be to ask it. There are 100s of posts using the abbreviation. Commenting under such a post would have been more appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, but under which one of the 100 posts? Hopefully having this as a stand alone question will make it easier to find for other new users.

Comment: hi Carl and a late , but warm, welcome to this forum. I just saw your question now. I may be one of those "senior" (?) members who types mma all the time. The reason and the meaning are well explained by the other commenters. Another shortcut you might run into is "WB", which stands for "Workbench". I agree with @Ajasja that making a stand alone question of this, offers better visibility to the answer.

Comment: @rm-rf The shortname no longer works in text cell now, not sure when it happens, at least since _v12.3_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MMA = Mma = mma = MatheMaticA = Mathematica`

Comment: MatheMaticA? ... R.M ... you are definitely a toad